# SQL Limits Within Columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm a noob to SQL and am currently using SQLite and have come across an issue I cannot seem to resolve or find an answer to (my deep sense is that I'm not asking it correctly via Google). Extremely rudimentary for most here, so my apologies -- but also a huge 'Thank You' -- in advance. Here's the issue.

I have a social security names file which I would like to parse based on name, gender, and the top/bottom 30 occurrences. When I do the code below, it just spits back the alphabetical order to the first 30 males names with 6 occurrences. The same for when I run females.

```
SELECT * 
FROM names_1899
WHERE Occurrences BETWEEN '5' AND '6'
AND Sex = 'M' OR 'F'
LIMIT 30
```

which spits out something great, but not what I'm not looking for (not the complete list of 30 to save space):

```
Alberto M   6
Alcide  M   6
Alferd  M   6
Almer   M   6
Alpha   M   6
Alto    M   6
Andres  M   6
Armond  M   6
Armstead    M   6
Arvil   M   6
```

Ideally, I would like it to produce a list like above with 30 males and 30 females, both either from the top/bottom 30 occurrences.

If I add a GROUP BY and ORDER BY, it also is meaningless to me:

```
SELECT * 
FROM names_1899
WHERE Occurrences BETWEEN '5' AND '6'
AND Sex = 'M' OR 'F'
GROUP BY Sex
ORDER BY Occurences ASC
LIMIT 30
```

simply producing just the top male name:

```
Alberto M   6
```

Again, thank you, in advance, to anyone who can help me on this terribly simple problem. Your time is certainly appreciated.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you, sir! This also helps me dig a but deeper into the structure of your syntax. Again, very much appreciated, sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT n.*
FROM (SELECT n.*, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sex ORDER BY sex) as seqnum
      FROM names_1899 n
      WHERE Occurrences BETWEEN 5 AND 6 AND  -- sounds like a number, not a string
            Sex IN ('M', 'F')
     ) n
WHERE seqnum <= 30;
```

The `ORDER BY` clause is optional in SQLite, so you can also write this as:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sex) as seqnum
```

Comment: Dont you think `ORDER BY sex` will give only Females.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai . . . It has no real effect because `sex` is used for partitioning.  Some databases require the `order by` clause, I by force of habit I always include one.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, I believe I added my comment in the wrong place. Ha! Always a soup sandwich with new things. Thank you, sir, for your help! Very helpful and opens the door to more learning.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment, and well, it's a kind of answer at that, too :-)

Writing a query starts with a precise idea of what to select. To me it looks like you are trying to write the query before you have the rules straight.

Let's say it's not 30, but 2 top / bottom occurrences, not 30 but 2 males / females you want to select. This lets us create sample data that we can work with:

```
name    sex   occurrences
Albert  M     6
Alfred  M     6
Bill    M     6
Jack    M     6
Jane    F     5
Jill    F     5
Mary    F     5
Robert  M     2
Sam     M     2
Tom     M     2
```

You see there can be a lot of ties. The top / bottom 2 occurrences? Well there are 4 top, 3 bottom and they don't even include any female. Or did you mean the top / bottom 2 per sex? Then we'd have 4 top males and 3 bottom males. And three top females who are also the three bottom females.

Of all these rows, which would you consider to show? Would you have any preferences applied?

Get the algorithm first. Then write the query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was trying to be very careful to avoid the problem you present. Perhaps I was not clear enough in my description. Whether it's 30, 2, 17, or 112, the problem was I had the question (rules), but could not articulate it in SQL--or for that matter, in performing a Google search. The top names are "easy" to identify since many are not repeating occurrences, so to say a name is a "#5" is easy. But to say a name is "bottom" is harder still because the SS system stops at 5 occurrences for privacy reasons. Therefore, there are many 5's listed alphabetically.